# How to not overwrite the value at the time of inputting values in a class?

Tags: java, class, variables, input, methods

In this case, I input a name. I want to input a name from main class and then pass it to newClass. When I try to input another name again, I've seen that the name before is overwritten.

```
public class JavaApplication107 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte number;
    NewClass obj = new NewClass();
    do{
        System.out.println("MENU : ");
        System.out.println("1. Show Data");
        System.out.println("2. Input Data");
        System.out.println("3. Exit");
        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input Number : ");
        number = sc1.nextByte();
        switch (number){
            case 1:
                obj.setShowBiodata();
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.print("Input your name : ");
                String strTmp = sc2.nextLine();
                obj.setName(strTmp);
                break;
        }
    }while(number != 3);
}}
```

> Blockquote

```
public class NewClass {
private String mName;
void setName(String name){
    mName = name;
}
void setShowBiodata(){
    System.out.println("Name : " + mName);
}}
```

So I can get more than one name

Comment: Yes? Because that is what `setName` does? Where else is the new (or old) name supposed to be stored - that's unclear from your description

Comment: So, how I can make the method to not overwrite the value? Should I use array or another?

Comment: You still haven't explained what's supposed to happen. But it sounds like you want to use an `ArrayList<String>` (in this case preferable over a simple array)

Comment: You should use either an array or a list.

Comment: Do you just want the program to print out a list of names?

Comment: @Austin Yes, I input a name, then it will be printed. When choose case 2 again and input a namem it will be printed under the first name :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code it should print out all of the names

```
public class NewClass {
private String mName ="";
void setName(String name){
    mName = mName+"\n"+name;
}
void setShowBiodata(){
    System.out.println("Name : " + mName);
}}
```

Here is a way you could use an array

```
public class NewClass {
private String[] names = new String[20];
private int number = 0;
void setName(String name){
    names[number]= name;
    number++:
}
void setShowBiodata(){
 for (int i =0; i<number; i++)
    {
     System.out.println(names[i]);
    }   
}}
```

Comment: Thanks bro. But, can you help me if sometimes I want use an array?

Comment: I want to make a name for an index